# Is Klein's inequality due to Klein?

Tags: density-matrix, information-theory, entropy, history

You may be familiar with "Klein's inequality"; one form of it is
$$
-\operatorname{tr}(\rho \log \sigma) + \operatorname{tr}(\rho \log \rho) \ge 0,
$$
stating that relative entropy is nonnegative (where $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are density matrices). There are various other versions of it - some which are equivalent, and some which go by the same name but are inequivalent / more general. A rather general one is
$$
\operatorname{tr}(f(A)-f(B)-(A-B)f'(B)) \ge 0
$$
($f$ convex, such as $f(t) = t \log t$), which is what https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequality calls Klein's inequality. I'm curious about the origins of the Klein inequality (or perhaps I should say, inequalities, plural).

I see Nielsen and Chuang, for example, cite a paper, O. Klein, *Zur quantenmechanischen Begründung des zweiten Hauptsatzes der Wärmelehre*, Zeitschrift für Physik A 72 (1931), 767 – 775. However - and maybe I'm just bad at reading German or the notation - I don't think I actually recognize "Klein's inequality" in there.

Did Oskar Klein prove what's now called Klein's inequality? Or if he didn't, then who did, and when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell Klein never published the proof but the proof is rather attributed to him via word of mouth.

In the paper [Mean Entropy of States in Quantum‐Statistical Mechanics](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1664685) (free version available [here](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eknill/history/lanford/papers/LanfordMeanEntropyOfStates.pdf)), a form of Klein's inequality is given in Lemma 1. There is a footnote attached to the lemma which states the following:

> This lemma, together with its proof, was communicated to one of us (D.W.R.) by Professor R.Jost, who attributed it to O. Klein. If $\mathrm{Tr}[A] = \mathrm{Tr}[B]=1$, this lemma is a particular case of Theorem 1 of H. Umegaki, Kodai Math. Sem. Rep. 14, 59 (1962).

I believe the professor who attributed the inequality to Klein is [Res Jost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Res_Jost) who was working in Zürich at the time which is close to D.W.R. who was in Geneva.